# Big query using two UNIQUE statements in query

Tags: google-bigquery

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  unique(a) AS un_a,
  unique(b) AS un_b,
FROM x.y

GROUP BY id
```

I want unique values for a (un_a) and unique values for b (un_b).
This errs as follows:

```
Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found un_a and un_b
```

Running this query with only one UNIQUE statement works as intended.  What's going on here?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually it works!

Result look something like below:

```
Row id  un_a    un_b     
1    1     1       1     
           2       2     
           3       3     
                   5     
2    2     5       5     
           6       6
```

Please note: BigQuery automatically flattens query results, so if you use your query as top level query, the results `won't contain repeated fields`.
`Use it as subselect` that produces intermediate results for immediate use by the same query or `save this to table` using respective options (Allow Large Results and UnFlatten Results) or you need to use it.

The error you are getting - is because you are trying to output two independent repeated fields and BigQuery doesnt handle this. See [Flatten Operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#flatten) for more insight

> If for some reason this is not what you want to deal with  - you can
>   use below "workaround":

Below is potential workaround, assuming you need to present for each id list of all a in un_a and list of all b in un_b.

```
SELECT id,   
  GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(UNIQUE(a))) AS un_a,
  GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(UNIQUE(b))) AS un_b,
FROM x.y
GROUP BY id
```

Result should like:

```
Row id  un_a    un_b     
1    1  1,2,3   1,2,3,5  
2    2  5,6 5,6
```